# Snapshot test for a React component with `useId` is fragile

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, snapshot-testing

I create a component with [`useId`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useId) as follows:

```js
function Form() {
  const id = useId();

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={id}>name</label>
      <input id={id} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I ran a snapshot test, I got a snapshot like the following. As you see, the ID of the DOM node is ":r1:".

The test is like follows:

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('Snapshot', () => {
  test('default', () => {
    const { asFragment } = render(<Form />);

    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

The snapshot is like follows:

```
exports[`snapshot 1`] = `
<DocumentFragment>
  <div>
    <label
      for=":r1:"
    >
      name
    </label>
    <input
      id=":r1:"
    />
  </div>
</DocumentFragment>
`;
```

If I add other tests, the snapshot test can fail because the DOM node may get a different ID, like ":r2:", ":r3:" and so on.

Is there a way to create robust snapshot tests for a component with `useId`?

I tried to make a mock for `useId` like following. It actually works.

```js
let id = 0;

beforeEach(() => {
  id = 0;
});

const generateId = () => ++id;

jest.mock('react', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react'),
  useId: generateId,
}));
```

I understand that `useId` just generates unique IDs, but doesn't imply that the same IDs will be expected when used in the same way. So I think we should not expect `useId` to return the same ID in normal usage.
With this mock, `useId` generates independent IDs for each test and the ID sequence it generates is always constant.

---

If you know of a better way, I'd be glad to know!

Comment: I'd generally suggest _not_ snapshot testing. They're often fragile. It's just change detection, it doesn't tell you whether the thing actually _works_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know what you mean, but I'm asking IN CASE I use snapshot test.